# Is there a way to restrict MKMapView Zoomlevel in iOS6

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, mkmapview

In one of my iPad apps, I use MKMapView to show regions and I have a weird issue. I use setRegion: animated: method to set a particular region from a noOf points. When I zoom from that particular point in the map, the map shows grids with no image of the place/location. Does anyone has the same issue before? Can someone provide a solution for how to handle this zoom level issue?

Attaching the image for more reference

Initially, I call the setRegion: method of mapview with a 2d co-ordinate and its span as 0.0014f for both latitude and longitude delta values. So I get the following image.

[image]

After that if I try to zoom in the mapview again, it goes to a situation like the following

[image]

My concern is, whether there is a way to restrict the zoom in to avoid the black layer display/how can I restrict the zoom in once mapview reaches its best possible zoomed cells.

Comment: You need to explain more clearly. Firstly, where are your pints. Maybe there is no data there. Maybe you are zoomed in too close. Do you mean zoom *from* those coordinates or zoom *to*.

Answer (score 0):

when you zoom in CLOSE the mapview wants to show the most detailed tiles and nothin else. For certain areas (gov, military or places where there is nothing) there are no tiles and it runs into that!

the problem is that you dont know beforehand where there are or aren't any tiles available.

what I could imagine:
when you zoom. 
`regionWillChange:` is called and then `willStartLoading:` should be called and then `mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:withError` in the case of no tiles

(im guessing here)

Comment: I agree. But in the Apple Maps implementation, they are giving a bouncing effect for such cases, they won't allow us to zoom in that close for once it reaches these condition. Is there a way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: although... mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:withError

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift** just you should use from following code for define minimum and maximum zoom limitation

```
let MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL = 16.5
let MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL = 18.0

extension UIViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(mapView.region.center.latitude, mapView.region.center.longitude)
            let zoomLevel = getZoomLevel()

            if MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL > zoomLevel || MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL < zoomLevel {
                let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinate, self.latestSpan)
                mapView.setRegion(region, animated:true)
            } else {
                self.latestSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0, 360 / pow(2, Double(zoomLevel-1)) * Double(mapView.frame.size.width) / 256)
            }
    }
}


func getZoomLevel() -> Double {
        var angleCamera = mapView.camera.heading
        if angleCamera > 270 {
            angleCamera = 360 - angleCamera
        } else if angleCamera > 90 {
            angleCamera = fabs(angleCamera - 180)
        }
        let angleRad = M_PI * angleCamera / 180
        let width = Double(mapView.frame.size.width)
        let height = Double(mapView.frame.size.height)
        let heightOffset : Double = 20
        let spanStraight = width * mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta / (width * cos(angleRad) + (height - heightOffset) * sin(angleRad))
        return log2(360 * ((width / 256) / spanStraight)) + 1
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//fix for ios6
if (region.span.latitudeDelta < .0005f)
    region.span.latitudeDelta = .0005f;
if (!region.span.longitudeDelta < .0005f)
    region.span.longitudeDelta = .0005f;
```

Make sure your region span for lat/lon isn't set too low and it will clear up.

Edit for clarity: In iOS6, setting a span delta too low (less than .0005 for instance) will cause it to literally set the map view to that region, regardless of if it has a tile set of images for that level of detail. IE: if you zoom in too far, there are no map tiles to represent the region. In iOS5 it would handle trying to zoom in too far and clip the region without causing an issue.

To fix this, you can set the region span lat and lon delta to a minimum value so the map still presents itself. Any time when setting the map region, or causing it to change, check for a minimum value.

Comment: No context or explaination.